# Apache Aurora 0.16.0 to 0.17.0 Upgrade

Tags: linux, apache-aurora

When we upgrade Apache aurora cluster from 0.16.0 to 0.17.0 , we are facing issue where job details is not shown in Aurora Web UI.

we are doing upgrade by changing the aurora docker version which we built and pushed to our local docker repositry.

Also is there is any steps or documentation to do properly upgrade the Aurora from version 0.16.0 to 0.17.0

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try browser incognito/privacy mode, or clearing browser cache. I've seen same issue because of caching